# change Aria-hidden to "false"

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to edit my wordpress template and i saw this snippet in "view > developer tools":

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true">::before == $0</i>
```

apparently that hides the content of :before

does changing "aira-hidden" to "false" show the content of :before?

I'm hoping it can be done via custom CSS, because that's the only way i know how to edit template.

if so, how do i do it?
if not, how do i go about it?

Comment: Sandy's answer below is accurate, but I suspect that you haven't shown us enough contextual code to let us know how to answer your question. It looks like css, but it's not normally where css is seen. Can you tell us more?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing related to show/hide `:before` in the webpage, it defines a way to make Web content and Web applications more accessible to people with disabilities.The hidden attribute is new in HTML5 and tells browsers not to display the element. The aria-hidden property tells screen-readers if they should ignore the element. Have a look at the w3 docs for more details: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden

`aria-hidden` means hidden to screen readers and similar tools